# SQL Server Stored Procedure Optimization needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, large-data

I am working with a stored procedure which generates rank for all nodes which are available in `SystemTree` table.

My stored procedure is working absolutely fine, but the problem is it takes too long to execute.

Here are the table details:

- `SystemTree` - 14000+ rows
- `PaymentSchedule` - 5000+ rows
- `MasterRankChart` - just 15 rows

I need to optimize my stored procedure. It takes at least 20 minutes to execute.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[RankGeneration]
    @CreatedUser nvarchar(128),
    @CreatedOn datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NodeKeyId nvarchar(128)

    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
        SELECT TOP 1000 NodeKeyId
        FROM SystemTree

    DECLARE @RankContainer TABLE
                           (
                                NodeKeyId nvarchar(128),
                                [Rank] nvarchar(512),
                                RankId int,
                                [LargestLeg] nvarchar(128),
                                [LargestLegNV] decimal(18, 2),
                                [SecondLargestLeg] nvarchar(128),
                                [SecondLargestLegNV] decimal(18, 2),
                                [ThirdPlusLeg] nvarchar(max),
                                [ThirdPlusLegNV] decimal(18, 2)
                            )

    OPEN MY_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @NodeKeyId

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @YearlyMinPNV bigint
        DECLARE @CurrentNodeId nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @TempNodeKeyId nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @TempChildKeyId nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @TempParentKeyId nvarchar(128)
        DECLARE @TempPlacementNode hierarchyid

        DECLARE @IMMEDIATEIDs TABLE
                              (
                                  NodeKeyId nvarchar(128),
                                  PlacementNode hierarchyid
                              )

        INSERT INTO @IMMEDIATEIDs
            SELECT NodeKeyId, PlacementNode
            FROM SystemTree
            WHERE PlacementNode.GetAncestor(1) = (SELECT PLACEMENTNODE
                                                  FROM SystemTree
                                                  WHERE NodeKeyId = @NodeKeyId)

        DECLARE @ChildIDs TABLE
                          (
                               ParentNodeId nvarchar(128),
                               NodeKeyId nvarchar(128)
                          )

       DECLARE @FinalNV TABLE
                        (
                              ParentNodeId nvarchar(128),
                              NodeKeyId nvarchar(128),
                              TotalNV decimal(18, 2)
                        )

       DECLARE @ResultNV TABLE
                         (
                             ImmediateNodeID nvarchar(128),
                             TotalNV decimal(18, 2)
                         )

       DECLARE @StorageNV TABLE
                          (
                              NodeKeyId nvarchar(128),
                              NV decimal(18, 2)
                          )

       INSERT INTO @StorageNV
           SELECT NodeKeyId, SUM(NV)
           FROM PaymentSchedule
           WHERE ClearDate IS NOT NULL
             AND NV IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY NodeKeyId

       DECLARE @i INT
       DECLARE @count INT

       SET @i = 0

       SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
       FROM @IMMEDIATEIDs

       WHILE @i < @count
       BEGIN
           SELECT
               @TempNodeKeyId = NodeKeyId,
               @TempPlacementNode = PlacementNode
           FROM 
               @IMMEDIATEIDs
           ORDER BY  
               NodeKeyId 
               OFFSET (@i) ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

       INSERT @ChildIDs
           SELECT
               @TempNodeKeyId AS ParentNodeId,
               t.NodeKeyId
           FROM SystemTree t
           WHERE PlacementNode.IsDescendantOf(@TempPlacementNode) = 1
             AND t.NodeKeyId IN (SELECT NodeKeyId
                                 FROM @StorageNV)
      SET @i = @i + 1
  END

  SET @i = 0

  SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
  FROM @ChildIDs

  WHILE @i < @count
  BEGIN
      SELECT
          @TempChildKeyId = NodeKeyId,
          @TempParentKeyId = ParentNodeId
      FROM 
          @ChildIDs
      ORDER BY 
          NodeKeyId 
          OFFSET (@i) ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

      INSERT INTO @FinalNV
      VALUES(@TempParentKeyId, @TempChildKeyId, 
             (SELECT SUM(NV) 
              FROM @StorageNV 
              WHERE NodeKeyId = @TempChildKeyId));

      SET @i = @i + 1
  END

  INSERT INTO @ResultNV
      SELECT ParentNodeId, SUM(TotalNV)
      FROM @FinalNV
      GROUP BY ParentNodeId

  DECLARE @MainCheckResult decimal(18, 2);
  DECLARE @LargestLeg nvarchar(128);
  DECLARE @MiddleCheckResult decimal(18, 2);
  DECLARE @SecondLargestLeg nvarchar(128);
  DECLARE @ThirdCheckResult decimal(18, 2);
  DECLARE @ThirdPlusLeg nvarchar(128) = NULL;

  SET @MainCheckResult = ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) TotalNV
                                 FROM @ResultNV
                                 ORDER BY TotalNV DESC), 0);

  SET @LargestLeg = (SELECT TOP(1) ImmediateNodeID
                     FROM @ResultNV
                     ORDER BY TotalNV DESC)

  SET @MiddleCheckResult = ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) TotalNV
                                   FROM @ResultNV
                                   WHERE ImmediateNodeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP(1) ImmediateNodeID
                                                                 FROM @ResultNV
                                                                 ORDER BY TotalNV DESC)
                                   ORDER BY TotalNV DESC), 0);

  SET @SecondLargestLeg = (SELECT TOP(1) ImmediateNodeID
                           FROM @ResultNV
                           WHERE ImmediateNodeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP (1) ImmediateNodeID
                                                         FROM @ResultNV
                                                         ORDER BY TotalNV DESC)
                           ORDER BY TotalNV DESC)

  SET @ThirdCheckResult = ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TotalNV)
                                  FROM @ResultNV
                                  WHERE ImmediateNodeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP(2) ImmediateNodeID
                                                                FROM @ResultNV 
                                                                ORDER BY TotalNV DESC)), 0);

  SET @ThirdPlusLeg = NULL;

  INSERT INTO @RankContainer
      SELECT TOP(1) 
          @NodeKeyId AS NodeKeyId,
          [Rank],
          Id AS RankId,
          @LargestLeg AS [LargestLeg],
          @MainCheckResult AS [LargestLegNV],
          @SecondLargestLeg AS [SecondLargestLeg],
          @MiddleCheckResult AS [SecondLargestLegNV],
          @ThirdPlusLeg AS [ThirdPlusLeg],
          @ThirdCheckResult AS [ThirdPlusLegNV]
      FROM 
          MasterRankChart
      WHERE 
          LargestLegNV + SecondLegNV + ThirdLegNV <= @MainCheckResult + @MiddleCheckResult + @ThirdCheckResult
          AND SecondLegNV + ThirdLegNV <= @MiddleCheckResult + @ThirdCheckResult
          AND ThirdLegNV <= @ThirdCheckResult
      ORDER BY 
          Priority

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @NodeKeyId
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

MERGE TrackRank AS Target
USING(SELECT 
          NodeKeyID, [Rank], [RankId], 
          [LargestLeg], [LargestLegNv],
          SecondLargestLeg, SecondLargestLegNV,
          ThirdPlusLeg, ThirdPlusLegNV
      FROM @RankContainer) AS Source ON (Target.NodeKeyId = Source.NodeKeyId)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET Target.[Rank] = Source.[Rank], 
            Target.[RankId] = Source.[RankId], 
            Target.[LargestLeg] = Source.[LargestLeg], 
            Target.[LargestLegNv] = Source.[LargestLegNv],
            Target.SecondLargestLeg = Source.SecondLargestLeg,   
            Target.SecondLargestLegNV = Source.SecondLargestLegNV, 
            Target.ThirdPlusLeg = Source.ThirdPlusLeg, 
            Target.ThirdPlusLegNV = Source.ThirdPlusLegNV

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (NodeKeyId, [Rank], [RankId], LargestLeg, LargestLegNV, 
            SecondLargestLeg, SecondLargestLegNV, 
            ThirdPlusLeg, ThirdPlusLegNV, 
            CreatedOn, UpdatedOn, IsDeleted, CreatedBy)
    VALUES (Source.NodeKeyID, Source.[Rank], Source.[RankId], 
            Source.[LargestLeg], Source.[LargestLegNv], 
            Source.SecondLargestLeg, Source.SecondLargestLegNV, 
            Source.ThirdPlusLeg, Source.ThirdPlusLegNV, 
            @CreatedOn, @CreatedOn, 0, @CreatedUser)

OUTPUT $ACTION, INSERTED.*, DELETED.*;

END
```

Please take a look any give me suggestions that how do I optimize it.

Thanks & Regards,

Mr. GO

Answer (score 1):

First sugestion would be to avoid `CURSOR` - everytime when you can avoid `CURSOR`, you should do it. Another advice, take a look at execution plan, maybe you willl be able to detect bottlenecks, etc.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions, will definitely  work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The following will be helpful to optimize the query execution time:

1. Try to run without using cursors
2. Create an index on referencing tables
3. Open SQL Server Profiler, then run the query and save the trace file in Profiler tool. Then open that trace file (`*.trc`) in SQL Server Tuning Advisor and estimate it, that will guide us to minimize the executing time.

Comment: I had tried your way. But it increases my execution time by 10 times.

Comment: Oh!, Really sorry @Mr.Go , For my query, SQL tuning Advisor shown some points. I followed that, I felt better, hence I advised You.